# Refactoring: extend abstract class but return implementation class

Tags: c#, generics, interface, refactoring

Currently I have:

```
class EntityFOO
{
    EntityFOO LoadFromXml(XDocument) {...}
    EntityFOO LoadFromDB(string) {...}
}

class EntityBAR
{
    EntityBAR LoadFromXml(XDocument) {...}
    EntityBAR LoadFromDB(string) {...}
}
```

I would like to refactor and extract an interface. I would want something like this:

```
abstract class Entity
{
    static string DatabaseConnectionString = "shared_across_implementations";

    abstract Entity LoadFromXml(XDocument);
    abstract Entity LoadFromDB(string);
}

class EntityBAR : Entity
{
    EntityBAR LoadFromXml(XDocument) {...}
    EntityBAR LoadFromDB(string) {...}
}
```

Notice that the implementations of `Entity`, return their own type `EntityBAR` and not the parent `Entity`. And assume I'll have to use `<Generics>` somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?:

```
abstract class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>
{
    static string DatabaseConnectionString = "shared_across_implementations";

    abstract T LoadFromXml(XDocument);
    abstract T LoadFromDB(string);
}

class EntityBAR : Entity<EntityBAR>
{
    EntityBAR LoadFromXml(XDocument) {...}
    EntityBAR LoadFromDB(string) {...}
}
```

Untested of course, and that `Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>` is messing with my intuition by making me thing it's some kind of weird type-recursion problem.  But I don't *think* it's a problem.

Though what concerns me even more is those `LoadFrom...` methods you have there.  If those are factories on the type itself, wouldn't they be `static`?  Which would change any kind of inheritance scheme.  **It seems strange to me that one would need an instance to build an instance.**

Maybe constructors with `string` and `XDocument` parameters would make more sense for this?  And since constructors don't have return types, that would kind of render the question moot.  Something *structurally* like this (also freehand and untested and kind of pseudo-code-ish):

```
abstract class Entity
{
    static string DatabaseConnectionString = "shared_across_implementations";

    protected Entity(XDocument) {...}
    protected Entity(string) {...}
}

class EntityBAR : Entity
{
    public EntityBAR(XDocument) : base(XDocument) {...}
    public EntityBAR(string) : base(string) {...}
}
```

Unless, of course, the operation of building/initializing the object is very *heavy* and itself involves other dependencies.  In that case a constructor isn't always a safe place to do that and the design would call for separate Factory objects.  *Those* can be instance-based and return *these* instances.

But having an instance-based initialization step *on the object itself* essentially means that consuming code needs to manually remember that building any given object is a two-step process.  Which introduces potential for bugs and other logical problems.

Comment: Seems to build OK, if I put `public`s on the methods and `override`s on the class methods, and variables in the signatures. Really didn't expect that to be possible :o)

Comment: @NikolaiDante: I think the design itself could use some improvements which render the question itself moot, though.  Been thinking on it a bit and updating the answer.

Comment: Those `Load*`, aren't factories, they actually don't instantiate objects (create), they just set the fields of a given object (load). Your solution works, even without the `where T`.

Comment: @dialex: Well, the `where T` constraint is mostly a sanity check to ensure that the inheritance tree doesn't get random types outside of what's intended.  It would "work", but could break with other types that you don't control.  If those methods aren't factories, maybe they shouldn't return the type then?  If they're meant to just *initialize* the object, then I'm still leaning toward the idea of using constructors.  Unless there's some compelling reason not to.  (Such as initializing with heavy operations, in which case a factory object *would* be called for.)

Comment: @David, You have a minor error at `class EntityBAR`, the constructors have the same name as the Base class.

Comment: Ok, check my edit, and please redo that sanity check, I never used it before. Thanks!

Comment: @dialex: There's no need to edit the answer to include your updates.  If the solution works then it works.  Though, honestly, I'm still *really* more concerned about the overall design of how these objects are initialized than with the syntax of using generics :)